# What type hint to specify when a function returns either an object of a certain type or None?

Tags: python-3.x, return-type, type-hinting

Since I discovered type hints in Python, I started using them, because I think they are useful for the reader of the code. I'm looking forward that these type hints will eventually become type static checkers in the future, because it would make code a lot more reliable, and that's very important for a serious project.

Apart from that, I've a lot of functions where the return type can either be `BSTNode` or `None`. It can be `None` for example because in a search function, if no `BSTNode` is found, `None` is simply returned. Is there a way of specifying that the return type could also be `None`?

Currently I'm using something as follows

```
def search(self, x) -> BSTNode:
    pass
```

I know I can use strings as type hints, but I'm not sure it's the correct or best way of doing it.

```
def search(self, x) -> "BSTNode | None":
    pass
```

Answer (score 10):

In Python prior to 3.10, the pipe doesn't have any special meaning in string-typed type hints. In Python ≤ 3.9, I'd thus stick to the ways [PEP 0484 documents](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types) for union types:

Either

```
from typing import Union

def search(self, x) -> Union[BSTNode, None]:
    pass
```

or, more concisely [but equivalent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)

```
from typing import Optional

def search(self, x) -> Optional[BSTNode]:
    pass
```

In Python ≥ 3.10, you can indeed use `|` to build representations of a union of types, even without the quotation marks. See [Jean Monet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67289747/674064), [PEP 604 -- Allow writing union types as X | Y](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604), [What’s New In Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-604-new-type-union-operator) or [the Python 3.10 documentation of the new `types.Union` type](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#types-union) for details.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing to the docs too. The fact that I will need to import `Union` or `Optional` in every module is however a con. Honestly, I'm using type hints too just because apparently they are part of the core of the language (Python 3.5).

Comment: Such is the nature of the Python standard library. Most of its content is namespaced. And for good reasons. "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"

Comment: Namespaces are good in many cases, but I expected this feature to be part of the language's core...

Comment: It kinda is. But it is a considerably _recent_ feature, so the chances that user code already defines the names `Union` or `Optional` are non-negligible and have to be accounted for.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes with Python 3.10, which introduces this very feature / syntax for Union types.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/#id11) it is possible to use the pipe `|` notation, equivalent to `Union`:

```py
def func() -> int | None:
    ...
my_var: int | None = None

# same as

from typing import Optional, Union

def func() -> Optional[int]:
    ...
def func() -> Union[int, None]:
    ...
my_var: Optional[int] = None
my_var: Union[int, None] = None
```

The feature is introduced in Python 3.10, but you can start using it in Python 3.8 and 3.9 (not sure for 3.7?) by importing annotations at the beginning of the file:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```